# Can you add “identify-this-video “?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

I’m asking this because, I have seen a video from YouTube and I need someone to identify it and tell from where was this video taken from. And I’m having problems with finding this. Can you please ad this tag?

Comment: Alex, this isn't something that's even remotely on-topic here.

Answer (score 6):

No, we should not.

Some sites accept "identify this" questions, but I don't see how that would even be remotely within the scope of this site. This site isn't about videos; it's about web applications. That there are web applications that show videos does not automatically make video *content* on-topic here.